# Insert random amount of dots to string with minimum different places?

Tags: c#, winforms, linq, .net-4.0

I want to insert a random amount of dots (from 1 to 7) on random parts of a string without breaking the layout.

This is my current code:

```
Random rand = new Random();
string[] words = iTemplate.Text.Split(' ');
string result = string.Empty;
for (int i = 0; i < words.Count(); i++)
{
    string word = words[i];
    if (rand.Next(i, words.Count()) == i)
    {
        for (int dots = rand.Next(1, 7); dots > 0; dots--)
            word += ".";
    }
    result += word + " ";
}
```

Is there a more efficient or nice LINQ option to it ?

Right now, since its random, there may be cases of no dots showing up. I have narrowed it by using `if (rand.Next(i, words.Count()) == i)` which seems to work but still some results only show 1 to 3 places having dots inserted.

How could I guarantee that the dots are inserted a minimum of 4 different places during the process ?

Sample data/result as per comment request:

```
string template = "Hi, this is a template with several words on it and I want to place random dots on 4 different random places every time I run the function";
```

Result 1:

```
string result = "Hi, this... is a template with several.. words on it and. I want to place random dots on 4 different random...... places every time I run the function";
```

Result 2:

```
string result = "Hi, this is a template. with several... words on it and I want to..... place random dots on 4 different random. places every time I run the function";
```

Result 3:

```
string result = "Hi, this. is a template with... several words on it and I want to place random.. dots on 4 different random....... places every time I run the.. function";
```

Comment: Can you give us before/after examples of what you'd want to accomplish, you're requirements are quite confusing.

Comment: @m-y added sample data and how the result would look like every time the function runs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will ensure that you add dots to at least 4 words, as well as not adding a trailing space to your final string.

```
Random rand = new Random();
string[] words = iTemplate.Text.Split(' ');
// Insert dots onto at least 4 words
int numInserts = rand.Next(4, words.Count());
// Used later to store which indexes have already been used
Dictionary<int, bool> usedIndexes = new Dictionary<int, bool>();
for (int i = 0; i < numInserts; i++)
{
    int idx = rand.Next(1, words.Count());
    // Don't process the same word twice
    while (usedIndexes.ContainsKey(idx))
    {
        idx = rand.Next(1, words.Count());
    }
     // Mark this index as used
    usedIndexes.Add(idx, true);
    // Append the dots
    words[idx] = words[idx] + new String('.', rand.Next(1, 7));
}
// String.Join will put the separator between each word,
// without the trailing " "
string result = String.Join(" ", words);
Console.WriteLine(result);
```

This code assumes that you do in fact have at least 4 words in iTemplate.Text.  If there's a chance that you won't, you should add some additional validation logic.

Answer (score 2):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Random rand = new Random();
        string[] words = "Now is the time for all good men to come to the aid of their countrymen".Split(new char[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        if (words.Length > 0)
        {
            // Generate a list of integers from 0 to words.Length - 1
            List<int> addIndices = Enumerable.Range(0, words.Length).ToList();
            // Shuffle those indices
            Shuffle(addIndices, rand);
            // Pick the number of words that will have dots added
            int addCount = rand.Next(4, Math.Max(4, words.Length));
            // Truncate the array so that it only contains the first addCount items
            addIndices.RemoveRange(addCount, addIndices.Count - addCount);

            StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
            for (int i = 0; i < words.Length; i++)
            {
                result.Append(words[i]);
                if (addIndices.Contains(i)) // If the random indices list contains this index, add dots
                    result.Append('.', rand.Next(1, 7));
                result.Append(' ');
            }

            Console.WriteLine(result.ToString());
        }
    }

    private static void Shuffle<T>(IList<T> array, Random rand)
    {
        // Kneuth-shuffle
        for (int i = array.Count - 1; i > 0; i--)
        {
            // Pick random element to swap.
            int j = rand.Next(i + 1); // 0 <= j <= i
            // Swap.
            T tmp = array[j];
            array[j] = array[i];
            array[i] = tmp;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 Nice that really simplifies my ugly code and seems to be faster from bm :) any ideas for the 2nd issue ?

Comment: @Guapo Third time's the charm.

Comment: Don't know why they down voted you ;( but it now looks too over complicated from the start point but I still appreciate your first reply `new String('.', rand.Next(1, 7))` was not aware I could do that and was a good learning.

Comment: The downvote probably came from the intermediate edit "Let me try again...", or what came before it which was wrong.

Comment: Anyhow, there should be a number of new things to learn there (StringBuilder, Enumberable, shuffling, etc.)

Comment: Surely does, but it also over complicates my initial problem. What I meant to say on the previous reply is that wasn't me who down voted as my arrow still orange but it says 0 and your feedback was very good initially so I feel sad for the down vote.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you need at least 4 different places, you need at least four dots. You do it in two parts - first choose the 4 words that get a dot at the end (that is, choose a word at random, add a dot to it, and make sure you don't choose it again), then choose 3 words at random, with repetitions, and add dots to them.

Comment: Well I don't want to make several loops to complete the task that's why I am looking for alternatives or perhaps a pretty LINQ that can do it all.

Comment: You just need two loops. I doubt you can get a LINQ expression to be more readable than the two loops (in this case, not every case of course).

Comment: Well I have managed to do it with the main `for` only but still doesn't look appealing which is why perhaps with LINQ it could, so I thinked.

Answer (score 0):

Just for fun and as terse as I can make it:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var random = new Random();

            var iTemplate = "Hi, this is a template with several words on it and I want to place random dots on 4 different random places every time I run the function";    
            var result = iTemplate;

            while (new Regex("\\. ").Matches(result).Count < 4)
                result = result.TrimEnd()
                    .Split(' ')
                    .Aggregate(
                        string.Empty,
                        (current, word) =>
                            current + (word + (((word.EndsWith(".") || (random.Next(1, 100) % 10) != 0)) ? "" : new string('.', random.Next(1, 7))) + " ")
                        );

            Console.WriteLine(result);
            Console.Read();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks interesting but the "while and regex" on the middle of it just don't make me like it. I will poke around with your idea and see if I can come up with something.

Comment: Twas just for fun but it works... and it uses Linq stuff which is fun :)